# Using PySpark in a Microsoft SQL Server using JDBC for connection

Tags: sql-server, pyspark, jdbc

I'm using PySpark in a Microsoft SQL Server using [JDBC](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) for connection.

```py
query = """(
WITH table_1 AS (
    SELECT
        code_1,
        a
    FROM my_database_table_1
),

table_2 AS (
    SELECT
        code_2,
        b
    FROM my_database_table_2
)

SELECT
    table_1.code_1 AS tb1_code_1,
    table_2.code_2 AS tb2_code_2
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2
ON table_1.code_1 = table_2.APRCH_CODIGO
) AS _
"""

df_python = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=query, properties=properties)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting such error?

**Edit 1:**

1. I replaced `==` by `=` in the `INNER JOIN` clause.
2. I didn't include a `,` after the closing parenthesis in table_2, as it's not [necessary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-use-multiple-cte-definitions-in-a-single-query).
3. `(` and `) as _` is [required](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html#push-down-a-query-to-the-database-engine) by JDBC.

To simplify, this is another query that returns the same error as the query above:

```py
query = """(
WITH table_1 (code_1)
AS
(
    SELECT code_1
    FROM my_database_table_1
)
SELECT code_1
FROM table_1
) as _
"""
```

And this is a query that works:

```py
query = """(
SELECT code_1
FROM my_database_table_1
) as _
"""
```

I'm starting to think that the `(` and `) as _` clauses, [required](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html#push-down-a-query-to-the-database-engine) by JDBC, may be causing problems with the `WITH` clause.

**Edit 2:**

Well, apparently [CTEs simply don't work with this driver](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/1340), so I'll have to find another way out without using `WITH`.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `(` and `) as _` that are wrapping the overall query?

Answer (score 0):

In sql the equality operator is = and not ==, you put == there in the JOIN, maybe this is the error

Answer (score 0):

In sql the equality operator is = and not ==, you put == there in the JOIN, maybe this is the error.

try with this code

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os

driver = "/home/romerito/Documents/apache-spark-3.1.2/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre11.jar"

spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder 
    .appName("load-sample-jdbc")
    .master("local[2]")
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", driver)
    .getOrCreate()
)

credentials = (
    readCredentials(os.getcwd()+f"/others/credentials-mssql.txt")
)
server   = credentials['server']
port     = credentials['port']
database = credentials['database']
user     = credentials['user']
password = credentials['password']

connection = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{server}:{port};databaseName={database}"
    
     
query = """(
WITH table_1 AS (
    SELECT
        code_1,
        a
    FROM my_database_table_1
),

table_2 AS (
    SELECT
        code_2,
        b
    FROM my_database_table_2
),

SELECT
    table_1.code_1 AS tb1_code_1,
    table_2.code_2 AS tb2_code_2
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2
ON table_1.code_1 = table_2.APRCH_CODIGO
) AS _
"""

query = spark.read \
     .format('jdbc') \
     .option('url', f'{connection}') \
     .option('user', f'{user}') \
     .option('password', f'{password}') \
     .option('dbtable', f'{query}')
     
query.show()
```